# CanCan ruby on rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authorization, cancan

I'm just starting a new project in Rails and I wanted to add some CanCan roles checking to app. What have I done:
1. Installed proper gem
2. Included in gemfile "cancan"
3. Created ability class
4. In my ApplicationController - added "check_authorization"

But still, I get

> undefined local variable or method `authorize_resource' for ApplicationController:Class

or

> undefined local variable or method `check_authorization' for ApplicationController:Class

error.
Somebody got any ideas what can be the reason why?

My cancan version is 1.6.7.
Gem version is 1.9.1

Comment: Jeez, I'm an idiot. I have done all of this (including installation of a gem) WITHOUT restarting the server. Sorry for making noise. Children, remember - ALWAYS RESTART THE SERVER AFTER GEM INSTALLATION!

Comment: thank you for this… I make dumb errors like this all the time

Answer (score 2):

As the author @Animattronic said, restart your Rails server.